# How do I install themes for the Terminal? (Mac)

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-elcapitan

I'm new to doing development work on a Mac. I picked up my Mac again recently, updated to El Capitan, and I've been using the Terminal a lot more. I decided I wanted to modify the colors and stuff so I got to digging around the web. It quickly became apparent that you can do a lot to improve the Terminal. Anyways... I came across [this theme](https://github.com/altercation/solarized/tree/master/osx-terminal.app-colors-solarized) and I have no idea how to install/use it.

I know this isn't exactly a coding problem, but I wasn't sure where else to post. (I'm sure there's some super meta Terminal forum threads somewhere, I just couldn't find them)

Any help is appreciated! I noticed some stuff about "xterm-256color" in the README.md file. Also note that this theme is like 3 years old.

Comment: Your question is better suited to [apple.se] or [su], as it is not programming related.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Terminal -> Preferences`.

Under the `Profiles` tab, click the settings gear near the bottom and click `Import...`

You should be able to choose your theme file to import it.

Comment: can I delete the imported file after apply it?

Comment: Yes, it appears you can delete the .terminal file after importing it. Just tried it now (on MacOS 10.13.5)